# Grails GORM linked list via hasOne

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I can create a top-down, one-to-many tree of Nodes with this:

```
static belongsTo = [parent: Node]
static hasMany = [nodes: Node]
static mappedBy = [nodes: 'parent']
```

With this there is only the parent_id fk in the table, and both parent and the injected children objects can be queried, a bidirectional arrangement.

Now I want to do the same thing so that it is a top-down one-to-one association, in essence a linked list instead of a tree.  Naively I thought changing "hasMany" to "hasOne" might do it:

```
static belongsTo = [parent: Node]
static hasOne = [link: Node]
static mappedBy = [link: 'parent']
```

but this ends up expecting a real "link" property, or bombs in some other way as I try variations.  How should I be doing it so that I can query in both directions, and have only a single parent_id fk property?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest u use [embedded](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html) as replancement